# Dropbox API: Get Notified On File Events Without Polling

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I found [this post on getting Notified when a file changes on dropbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633410/get-notified-when-a-file-changes-on-dropbox).  The problem is that the "/delta" API endpoint requires polling.  I want instead to subscribe to events about file changes.

Ideally, I could subscribe to both "new file" and "file updated" events for a specific folder.  I could then give dropbox a URL pointing to my own app that would be called when those events occurred.  This is similar to how Twilio works.  You can provide a URL to be POSTed to whenever your phone number receives a text message, and then your app can respond to POSTs to that URL however it wants.  This seems like a much more elegant solution than polling -- is there any way to do it with the dropbox API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE 6/5/2014**

We actually have webhooks now: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/webhooks

(original reply below)

---

No, Dropbox doesn't support this.

BTW, the general term for the sort of notification you describe is a "webhook."

Comment: I guess I can assume this answer is definitive since you're the developer advocate :).  What is the reason db doesn't provide webhooks like this?  It seems that the polling solution is worse for both parties: developers need to poll, and db servers get hammered unnecessarily.

Comment: I agree with you on the benefits of webhooks for this. I just started working at Dropbox, so I'm not sure why things got implemented the way they did, but I'll try to learn. :-)

Comment: I should point out that if you're building a mobile app, the [Sync API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync) does support change notifications using long-polling under the hood.

Comment: Adding to this, we've exposed long polling in the Core API too: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#longpoll-delta. This can be used to efficiently wait for changes on a single account per connection.

Answer (score 4):

http://developers.box.com/webhooks/

it seems like Box API has webhook. You may want to try it.

Answer (score 2):

I received an email today regarding Dropbox WebHooks that is in the beta phase:

> If you're interested in helping us out, just click through to fill out
>   your information, and we'll be in touch:
>
> https://dropboxapi.wufoo.com/forms/dropbox-webhooks-api-beta-feedback-contact-info
>
> Happy Dropboxing!

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox now offers webhooks, although not with a event_type filter

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/90/announcing-dropbox-webhooks